# Math.Round(double,2) returns 1 decimal

Tags: c#, string, math, decimal, string-formatting

Why does this code returns 1 `decimal` instead of 2

```
p = Math.Round(9431.796, 2);
```

If I replace this with `p = Math.Round(9431.796, 4);` It still returns 1 `decimal`

Comment: `.796` rounded to 2 dp is `.80` the string you are probably creating is ignoring the 0 due to your formatting.

Comment: P was a double but thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot because `9431.80` is equal to 9431.8. In this case however I guess that you want to print it out with specific format, which can be done like this:

```
string p = Math.Round(9431.796, 2).ToString("0.00");
```

Answer (score 4):

If you round `9431.796` to two decimal places, you will get `9431.80`.

Numerical data types don't store actual digits. They store a representation of a number. `9431.80` is exactly the same number as `9431.8`, and there will be no distinction made between them when they are stored in a `decimal` or `double` variable.

So if you display `9431.80` without doing anything to format it a certain way, it will display as `9431.8`. So the problem is with your understanding of how numbers are stored in numerical datatypes.

You create a string with a certain number of decimal places by using `.ToString()`. You don't need to use `Math.Round()` in this case. `.ToString()` will round it:

```
var p = 9431.796.ToString("0.00");
Console.WriteLine(p);                // 9431.80
```

Comment: Well, I knew this I feel dumb now but I did not know how to keep the extra 0 at the end thanks for your answer

Comment: @robbii15 No need to feel dumb. We all have gaps in our understanding. :)

Comment: Just the thing that I forgot it automaticly filters the 0's away behind the ,

Answer (score -1):

`Math.Round(9431.796, 2)` returns one decimal becauses it rounds to 9431.80. When displayed, it gets rid of the last 0, that's why you only see one decimal.
`Math.Round(9431.796, 4)` should definitely return 9431.796. Could you test it again?

Answer (score -1):

Since it rounds to `9431.80` it delete the last `0` which is useless. I would use :

```
int nbDec = 2;
p = Math.Round(9431.796, nbDec );
Console.Out.WriteLine(p.ToString("#,##0." + new string('#',nbDec ));
```

Which will display `9,431.80`.

If you want more or less decimal, just change the `nbDec` value.